# PHP Web Service Nusoap in Windows Azure

Tags: php, web-services, azure, nusoap

I'm trying to set a web service written in PHP using NuSOAP into Windows Azure. I have been investigating for a while now, and don't find how to do it.

I tried just setting it as a normal PHP app but it didn't work.

Has someone already made something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to get any sort of PHP application up and running on Windows Azure. Check out Microsoft's official website for PHP on Windows Azure here
http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/tutorials

You may be most interested in this tutorial
http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/build-and-deploy-a-windows-azure-php-application